# This wooCommerce theme code showing products on home page, but I want to display product categories

Tags: php

```
<div class="section">  
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-heading text-center">
        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'woo_products_section_title', '' ) != '' ) : ?>
            <h4><?php echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'woo_products_section_title', '' ) ); ?></h4>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'woo_products_section_desc', '' ) != '' ) : ?>
            <div class="sub-title"><span><?php echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'woo_products_section_desc', '' ) ); ?></span></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="woo-tabs-section row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <?php
                $query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                ) );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                    echo do_shortcode( '[' . esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'woo_products_settings', 'recent_products' ) ) . ' per_page="' . absint( get_theme_mod( 'products_per_page', '8' ) ) . '" columns="' . absint( get_theme_mod( 'products_per_row', '4' ) ) . '"]' ); 
                else : 
                ?>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'No products found', 'giga-store' ) ?>
                    </div>  
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) : ?>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'This area needs to function properly installed WooCommerce Plugin. You can disable this area in customizer admin panel.', 'giga-store' ) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
  function product_cats() {
$output = array();
$categories = get_terms( array(
'orderby'      => 'name',
'pad_counts'   => false,
'hierarchical' => 1,
'hide_empty'   => true,
) );
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    if ($category->taxonomy == 'product_cat' ) {
        $output[$category->slug] = array(
            'label' => $category->name,
            'value' => $category->slug
        );
    }
}
//return array('options'=>$output);
return $output;
```

}

Comment: <?php
     $query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
     ) );
     if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
      echo do_shortcode( '[' . esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'woo_products_settings', 'recent_products' ) ) . ' per_page="' . absint( get_theme_mod( 'products_per_page', '8' ) ) . '" columns="' . absint( get_theme_mod( 'products_per_row', '4' ) ) . '"]' ); 
     else : 
     ?>
      <div class="text-center">
       <?php esc_html_e( 'No products found', 'giga-store' ) ?>
      </div> 
     <?php endif; ?>

Comment: see my hole code in code section . It is giga store theme /home page/ product section code.

Comment: check code and use product_cats() function it will help you